# Finding the minimum value in lists inside a dataframe with TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, nested-lists

I've generated a Dataframe with a column of lists, but if there are no values, there's a NaN instead.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Lists', 'Min'])
df['Lists'] = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], float('NaN') ]
print(df)

       Lists  Min
0  [1, 2, 3]  NaN
1  [4, 5, 6]  NaN
2  [7, 8, 9]  NaN
3        NaN  NaN
```

I would like for `df['Min']` to contain the minimum value of the corresponding list in the same row. Thus:

```
       Lists  Min
0  [1, 2, 3]  1
1  [4, 5, 6]  4
2  [7, 8, 9]  7
3        NaN  NaN
```

However, when I try list comprehension I receive an error.

```
df['Min'] = [min(x) for x in df.Lists.tolist()]
```

Produces the error

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

How can I find the minimum of each list?

Comment: The last row in the dataframe has a single NaN, not a list, in the Lists column.  Presumably this is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily fix your list comprehension by checking if the value is NaN/iterable/a list:

```
df['Min'] = [x if pd.isna(x) else x for min(x) in df.Lists.tolist()]

df['Min'] = [min(x) if hasattr(x, '__iter__') else float('nan') for x in df.Lists.tolist()]

df['Min'] = [min(x) if isinstance(x, list) else float('nan') for x in df.Lists.tolist()]
```

Or use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [`groupby.min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.min.html):

```
df['Min'] = df['Lists'].explode().groupby(level=0).min()
```

Output:

```
       Lists  Min
0  [1, 2, 3]  1.0
1  [4, 5, 6]  4.0
2  [7, 8, 9]  7.0
3        NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

make list without nan & make DataFrame for finding minimum

```
tmp = df['Lists'].dropna()
df['Min'] = pd.DataFrame(tmp.tolist(), index=tmp.index).min(axis=1)
```

df:

```
    Lists       Min
0   [1, 2, 3]   1.0
1   [4, 5, 6]   4.0
2   [7, 8, 9]   7.0
3   NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is that the list comprehension cannot iterate on the value in the 4th row, the `NaN`. That is what is causing the 'float' error.

One way to solve this is to replace all the `NaN`s with `NaN` inside a list, like so: `[NaN]`

```
df['Lists'] = df['Lists'].fillna({i: [float('NaN')] for i in df.index})
df['Min'] = [min(x) for x in df.Lists.tolist()]
print(df)

       Lists  Min
0  [1, 2, 3]  1.0
1  [4, 5, 6]  4.0
2  [7, 8, 9]  7.0
3      [nan]  NaN
```